# JQuery UI slider max value as video duration

Tags: jquery, video, attributes, max, duration

I have HTML5 video.

```
<video id="Video1">
<source src="/media/thevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

And I have JQuery UI slider:

```
<div id="slider2" style="width:100%;" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $( "#slider2" ).slider({
            value:0,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 95,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
           $( "#amount2" ).val( ": " + ui.value );
```

I can get the video duration, I can put it into `<div>` like:

```
myVid=document.getElementById("Video1");
function(){vidduration=myVid.duration;};
function(){document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=vidduration.toFixed(1)+" seconds";};
```

What I want to do, is to set the slider's max attribute as the duration of Video1. Can someone help me with this? 
Internet did not tell me much about it, as I am kinda new to this..

P.S. `max: vidduration.toFixed(0),` did not work.

Comment: So I guess there is no real solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by writing this:

```
window.onload= $(function() {
myVid=document.getElementById("Video1");
setTimeout(function(){vidduration= myVid.duration;},300);
setTimeout(function(){$("#slider2").slider("option", "max", vidduration.toFixed(0))},330);
}
```